# "Multiple Connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed" when using same credentials

Tags: windows, windows-10, network-shares, credentials

I've having trouble with Windows 10 and mounting multiple shares on a NAS on the network. Everytime I log in I get an error telling me that some network drives couldn't be mounted. If I then try to access the drive that failed I get the following error:

> A  error occurred while reconnecting to  {Drive Letter} to {UNC Path}
> Multiple Connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed, Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.

The fact is, however, is that error is wrong; I have expressly told Windows to use the *same* credentials for both mount points.

I have, however, checked the Credentials Manager, and confirmed only one credential is stored for the NAS; there is only one.

The only way to fix the problem is, as it suggest, to remove both the mounted network paths, and then readd them. Of course when I do this I tell the device I am using different credentials and enter them. It remembers the username I previously configured and I enter the password. I then remount the other drive, exactly the same process (both are using the **same** username and password).

I can then reboot and, oh one fails.

The only thing I can think of is that Windows is being, for lack of a better word "dumb". One of the drives accepts anonymous authentication and I *assume* Windows in it's ultimate ~~wisdom~~ stupidity is therefore going straight for the anonymous authentication and then being dumb for the second as it tries to then use different credentials (the ones I originally explicitly defined and it ignored for the prior connection).

How do I get around this "feature" of Windows, or stop it being dumb? Can I force Windows to mount the Share that requires a username and password first, thus ensuring the second uses those credentials? Everything I search just brings me to configuring the credentials in the Credential manager, but I've confirmed those are correct, I just (assume) Windows is choosing not to use them when the Network Share doesn't ask for a username and password; even though I have explicitly told it to use specific credentials.

FYI I do *not* want to stop the share point allowing anonymous authentication on the "public" one, that is intentionally like that.

Comment: Questions: (1) Are the network shares you are mounting defined as permanent? (2) After logon that gives this error, run a Command Prompt as administrator and enter the command `net use`. Do you see drives listed that are not assigned a letter and have the form `\\IP\folder`? If you have any, does running `net use /delete \\IP\folder` fix the problem? (3) Try restarting the “Workstation” service,  (4) Try to connect one as `\\IP\Share1` and the other as `\\ServerName\Share2`.

Comment: *"Are the network shares you are mounting defined as permanent?"* Yes. Annoyingly it hasn't done it after a couple reboots this time (been doing it all last week, so of course after i post about it, it doesn't). On 4, I had considered this, as Windows treats as IP and DNS name as "different" hosts, but I don't *want* to go that route as it feels "clunky". I'm sure it'll happen again tomorrow when i take the device to the office and back so will advice on 2 and 3 (2 currently have both the `\\ServerName`)

Answer (score 0):

Possible actions:

- After a logon that gives this error, run Command Prompt as administrator and
  enter the command `net use`.
  If you see drives listed that are not assigned a letter and have the form `\\IP\folder`,
  run `net use /delete \\IP\folder`
- Try restarting the `Workstation` service
- Try to connect one as `\\IP\Share1` and the other as `\\ServerName\Share2`.